# Convert click event into Observable Mouse Event (Angular 2/4)

Tags: javascript, angular, drag-and-drop, mouseevent, observable

I'm trying to make Drag and Drop functionality on my own without use any opensource modules. When I use single element and create Observables in the controller like:

```
  const mouseup = Observable.fromEvent(item, 'mouseup');
  const mousemove = Observable.fromEvent(document, 'mousemove');
  const mousedown = Observable.fromEvent(item, 'mousedown');
```

Drag works fine. But when I bind event in template with (click) and pass $event to controller like:

```
(click)="click($event)"
```

I can't convert event into observable 'fromEvent'. I tried 'of'/'from', nothing helped. Here is example of my const:

```
const mouseup = Observable.fromEvent(event.currentTarget, 'mouseup');
const mousemove = Observable.fromEvent(document, 'mousemove');
const mousedown = Observable.of(event); // of or from don't create MouseEvent
```

So, from code above mouseup and mousemove create MouseEvent Observable, but mousedown does not. As result, on my mind code below does not work. **I can be wrong, If somebody could me explain I would appreciate it.**

*My main training goal to create Drag and Drop on Observables*

Here is my code explains how I suppose to do:
Template with list of item. Each item could be moved into another list. Here is Templete:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="item" style="position: relative;" (click)="click($event)" *ngFor="let item of items">
    <img src="{{item.imageUrl}}" alt="">
    <h2>{{item.itemName}}</h2>
</div>
```

and my controller:

```
  click(e) {
   const mouseup = Observable.fromEvent(e.currentTarget, 'mouseup');
   const mousemove = Observable.fromEvent(document, 'mousemove');
   const mousedown = Observable.of(e.currentTarget, 'mousemove');

   const mousedrag = mousedown.mergeMap((md: any) => {
    const startX = md.clientX + window.scrollX,
      startY = md.clientY + window.scrollY,
      startLeft = parseInt(md.target.style.left, 10) || 0,
      startTop = parseInt(md.target.style.top, 10) || 0;

    return mousemove.map((mm: MouseEvent) => {
      mm.preventDefault();
      return {
        left: startLeft + mm.clientX - startX,
        top: startTop + mm.clientY - startY
      };
    }).takeUntil(mouseup);
  });

  const subscription = mousedrag.subscribe((pos) => {
    e.currentTarget.style.top = pos.top + 'px';
    e.currentTarget.style.left = pos.left + 'px';
  });
}
```

Please don't judge strongly I just started to learn Observables, would be glad to hear any sugestion from You! Thank you in advance!

Comment: Check out https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/of.md. Observable.of(...) takes a number of arguments and puts them as consecutive values of a stream. What you want to do is make an interface like { target: HTMLElement; mouseAction: string; } and use that as the type/token of the of()-method

Comment: hi, ok I created Interface, but how to apply this type on .of()- method?

Comment: private mouseEventStream$ = new Observable<MouseActionAndTarget>();
(click) = onMouseAction($event, 'mouseClick')
onMouseAction(event, mouseAction: string): void { this.mouseEventStream$.next(/*parse into interface*/)}

Comment: oh, thanks! But I got type error.  MEthod next() does not exist on  MouseActionAndTarget. Here is screenshot: https://imgur.com/a/SzLOv

Comment: next() belongs to Observable (eg mouseEventStream$), not to the interface you defined

Comment: yeah, but why it does not see next() on Observable?

Comment: Oh sorry, my fault. You need to use Subject<MouseActionAndTarget>, not Observable. Its implementing the Observable interface and allows you to pass in values with the next method.

Comment: Than you Phil! Subject works. But acctually I don't understand what I should do next with this all. Here is screenshot what I have for now. https://imgur.com/a/v5OA6