# mouseup/down on entire SPA angular

Tags: javascript, angular, swiper.js, mousedown, mouseup

In my component class I have

```
@HostListener('document:mousedown', ['$event'])
onMouseDown() {
    this.holding = true;
}

@HostListener('document:mouseup', ['$event'])
onMouseUp() {
    this.holding = false;
}
```

In this project I'm also using [swiper library](http://idangero.us/swiper/api/). My swiper is 200px height and 100% width. Swiper use some own events catching for "grabing" elements to make it actually swipeable.

Now when I have my mouse on top of swiper element and I click above code doesn't catch the event.

This shoudln't happen but it is. Also what make it even weirder is that it doesn't catch only the left mouse click, right click works correctly.

How to make it works even when mouse is on top of swiper?

---

**Edit**

For some reason I'm not able to reproduce issue at online code playground, so I've created very basic app with just two components and I [pushed it to git](https://bitbucket.org/dopeCode/ng-hover-issue/src).

In this project I'm displaying `{{ holding }}` and as you can see (if you clone and `ng serve` this app) when clicking at the top or bottom of page it change from `false` to `true` but when clicking on swiper it doesn't catch `onMouseDown` and the value doesn't change.

Comment: using streams/observables might help, for hint: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47210194/convert-click-event-into-observable-mouse-event-angular-2-4

Comment: @BT101 could you provide more code from your component? I was able to get this working in a standard angular component https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zbp8mc?file=src/app/another.component.ts

Comment: For some reason I can not reproduce this on stackblitz. However I can add link to git repository demo with my issue. Do you want it?

Comment: I've added link to demo. All you need to do is: 1. clone project 2. npm install 3. ng serve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

because `Swiper` prevent the dispatching of internal DOM element, you can use [Event API](https://www.tutorialdocs.com/tutorial/swiper/api-events.html) from swiper to get what is happening inside Swiper main dom element.

For example on your case you can do something like this :

```
    this.mySwiper = new Swiper('.nav', {
        paginationClickable: false,
        grabCursor: true,
        loop: true,
        autoplay: 1000,
        slidesPerView: 3,
        spaceBetween: 50
    });

    this.mySwiper.on('touchStart', () => {
        this.touchService.triggerTouchStart();
    });
    this.mySwiper.on('touchEnd', () => {
        this.touchService.triggerTouchStop();
    });
```

You can introduce new service on your application to abstract to the rest of your application this trick to be binded on all mousedown | mouseup events. bellow you can find the implementation :

```
export class TouchService {
  private _manualControl$: Subject<boolean>;

  constructor() {
    this._manualControl$ = new Subject();
    // React to the document mouse event.
    fromEvent(document, 'mousedown').subscribe(() => this.triggerTouchStart());
    fromEvent(document, 'mouseup').subscribe(() => this.triggerTouchStop());
  }
  // Can be call manually to force new state.
  triggerTouchStart(): void {
    this._manualControl$.next(true);
  }

  triggerTouchStop(): void {
    this._manualControl$.next(false);
  }

  get touch$(): Observable<boolean> {
    return this._manualControl$.asObservable();
  }
}
```

Now you have observable which react on native `mousedown` and `mouseup` events and can also be trigger by manual API call like

```
    this.mySwiper.on('touchStart', () => {
        this.touchService.triggerTouchStart();
    });
    this.mySwiper.on('touchEnd', () => {
        this.touchService.triggerTouchStop();
    });
```

Finally you can use this service like following :

```
constructor(private touchService: TouchService) {
    this.touchService.touch$.subscribe(e => this.holding = e);
}
```

---

I can't prupose you pull request on your project because i don't have right to do it. [You can see it in action here](https://bitbucket.org/yghidouche/ng-hover-issue/branch/issues_1)

`git remote add fork https://bitbucket.org/yghidouche/ng-hover-issue`

`git fetch fork issues_1`

Comment: Thank you Yanis. By the way, how can I get this branch into my local? I'm doing `git fetch` and I don't see it: https://i.imgur.com/bIrN4IN.png

Comment: Because is another project, i have no access to your repo. check my update for getting access.

Comment: Oh it has same name and I didn't notice it's not mine repo :D Ok I'm gonna clone it

Comment: No need to clone it, you can link many repository to single git project, you have command on my edit.

Comment: my pleasure, notice i have not handle unsubscription on life cycle hook. But you should always unsubscribe manually when `service` or `component` are destroy. Otherwise you will have unexpected comportment and memory leak. Happy coding @BT101

Comment: Last question - why here (https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-with-swiper-ypwmtj?file=app%2Fhello.component.ts) it works without this observable logic?